# Session for both WordPress and NON-WP pages

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

Have a WordPress site, with a directory that has non-WordPress pages in it. (a couple of php files)

The non-WP pages will perform a function with another non-wordpress site, and set a few session variables.

It would be helpful if WP be able to read those variables too, but it seems to treat the files at /directory/ (the non-wp pages) as a different independent session.

I've tried starting the session from either the wordpress pages or the non-wordpress pages, trying both simultaneously, and just initiating the session_start() vs testing for existing session (if (!session_id()) { session_start(); }) on both sides.

I echo out the session ID, and depending on which side (wp or NON-wp) starts, it, the other just doesn't see a session. In fact, starting it in both (which should overwrite the other???), just makes two different concurrent session ID. And each set of pages retains its ID, so not like each is constantly getting a new one reset.

The Session should be global for the domain and for the browser/user, right? It should treat example.com/ and example.com/directory/ the same?? Am I missing something about sessions?

Or am I missing something about Wordpress? Is there some weirdness in WP or a setting somewhere that restricts its sessions to only the pages WP knows about? I know sessions aren't part of the WP core, so it would seem strange that this would be the case, but lacking info here.

I tried searching for solutions, but either I'm just using too broad search terms, or this isn't a common issue with both wp & non-wp pages and sessions.

NOTES: 1. Don't think any plug-ins are calling session. 2. Want to keep it server side (no cookies) 3. Did change the htaccess, but that was just rewrite for that directory (and changed it back) 4. Can't really merge the non-WP pages into the WP pages, so presumed session variables would work for the duration of the session.

Comment: Check the session cookie(s) in your browser when there are two 2 different sessions set up from wp and non-wp. Maybe there will be two different cookies...

Comment: Zoli- Thanks. But the fact that I can produce two different session IDs is a pretty good indicator I think. Plus this does nothing to tell me how to stop multiple sessions. Unless you are suggesting there is a way to check and differentiate on the fly between multiple cookies. But still using 1 session would seem to be less cumbersome.

Comment: You are right, my comment previous comment not complete enough. What I was trying to suggest is that you can start debugging further with given you find a non-standard session cookie name. Maybe you do have some WP plugin that uses sessions with a non-standard session cookie name.

Comment: BTW, it is not that hard to include WP's bootstrap file in your custom PHP files. Just require the wp-load.php from the root of WP, and you will have access to all the ecosystem of WP (functions, classes, global variables) in your custom PHP files. But you should still find the duplicate session issue first.

Comment: Zoli - Okay, your comment on "non-standard cookie names" helped. I found the source, and all is behaving again. (Also had some issue with the server inconsistently handling a few things (including sessions I think) that started all of this.

Comment: But could you elaborate more on the bootstrapping? I'm not actually serving anything up to viewers on the non-WP files (I do use one or two of the files with an include, but for the most part those files are for a different function). So I'm not sure I want the WP ecosystem in this case, but I am open to insight/suggestions. Thanks again for your help!